# WordPress : Send email after 25 day for author of post

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to convert any post in custom post type `banner` after 30 days to draft, I do that by below function (action), But i need after 25 days when author post this post to send email to him that told him that post we convert to draft.

How can do that ?

```
function ads_show_expire(){
  global $wpdb;
  $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'banner' AND post_status = 'publish'");
  if( !empty($result)) foreach ($result as $a){
      $show_time = get_the_time("Y-m-d", $a->ID );
      $show_time=date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+30 day", strtotime($show_time)));
      if ( $show_time < date("Y-m-d")){//compare 1 year after post with current time
          $my_post = array();
          $my_post['ID'] = $a->ID;
          $my_post['post_status'] = 'draft';
          wp_update_post( $my_post );
      }
  } // end foreach
}

add_action( 'init', 'ads_show_expire' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set cronjob which will execute every day and send mail and convert that post to draft. The code which you have write will be execute every time when any user will visit the page. So the best solution is to create cron-job for that.

Where condition to get 25 days old post 
$where .= " AND date(post_date) = '" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-25 days')) . "'";

```
 `if ( $show_time < date("Y-m-d")){//compare 1 year after post with current time
      $my_post = array();
      $my_post['ID'] = $a->ID;
      $my_post['post_status'] = 'draft';
      wp_update_post( $my_post );
      $user_info = get_userdata($a->post_author);
      $email = $user_info->user_email;
  }`
```

Comment: No, I don't need cronjob, No problem to execute my code every time when any user will visit the page. But how can send email ?

Comment: Ok then when you update the post then get the Author email and send mail on that email.

Comment: But how can get get the Author email of post ?

Comment: @Thirty5Seconds I have updated added code from where you will get author email

Comment: but how can send baftere 25 days?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91057/discussion-between-mitul-and-thirty-5seconds).

Answer (score 0):

It may help you,

- You should set cron job file using the cpanel, in that you have to write above code and also fetch the post date and compare that date with current date, it is match than write the email function to send the mail to told him that post we convert to draft.
  Below is the sample code of cron file that you should put in root folder of your wordpress folder for your reference:

`<?php // FOR DATABASE OPERATION
    include('../wp-load.php');
    // FOR GET_USERDATA FUNCTION & $WPDB
    include('../wp-includes/pluggable.php');
    wp-includes/author-template.php
    //sample email code
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: <test@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: test@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
    $to = "test@gmail.com";
    $subject = "subject text";
    $meesage = "test";
    $sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    if($sentmail)
    echo $msg = "Mail has been sent successfully...";
    else
    echo $msg = "Mail has been failed...";`

Before that you should your above function code.

You can get author email using below function:

`<?php the_author_email(); ?>`
OR
`<?php get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $userID ); ?>`